# How to get the last line of a file using cat command

Tags: macos, shell, unix, cat

I am writing a shell script in OSX(unix) environment. I have a file called `test.properties` with the following content:

`cat test.properties` gets the following output:

```
//This file is intended for 
//blah blah purposes
123
```

Using `cat` command, how can I get only the last line of the file ?

Comment: Use : `tail -1 file`

Comment: Yup. thanks a many.

Comment: It's probable because this is one of the "How do I use X to do Y?" questions where X does not do Y.  Such questions are not as useful as "How do I do Y?" or "What does X do?".

Comment: // , Those of us who think X will do Y, when, in reality, Z does Y (ahem) do benefit from such questions, in spite of their dubious pedagogy.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Don't use `cat`. `tail` was meant for this usecase exactly:

```
$ tail -1 ./test.properties
```

Comment: last small question: if I want to get the `last but second line` or `last but third line` ?

Comment: combine tail and head for example: `tail -2 | head -1`

Comment: // , très élégant

Answer (score 12):

Don't have enough reputation to comment Mureinik's post to answer your last question, but if you want to display a part of a file between known lines, you can try `sed -n '<line1>,<line2>p <filename>`.

If you don't know the lines, mix `tail` and `sed` : For your file :

```
tail -r test.properties | sed -n '2p'
```